# Add accordion functionality to bootstrap linked list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time with this. I'm trying to make it so when you click on a bootstrap linked-list item it expands to show additional text in an accordion fashion.

This is my code: http://www.bootply.com/6zXrStZ2o3

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap 3 List Groups</h1>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
      Linked item in .list-group
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Linked item in .list-group with Chevron and Badge
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so when I click on the title of one of the linked lists it expands to show more content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `data-toggle="collapse"` and a `data-target` to element to automatically assign control of a collapsible element

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap 3 List Groups</h1>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#info1">
      Linked item in .list-group
      <div id="info1" class="collapse">More Info #1</div>
    </a>    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#info2">Linked item in .list-group with Chevron and Badge
      <div id="info2" class="collapse">More Info #2</div>
    </a>    
  </div>  
</div>
```